# L'emploi de l'article défini ou non ?

Tags: grammaire, articles

Quand on demande à un élève de parler de ses matières du lundi, peut-il répondre par:

> Le lundi, j'ai maths, histoire, anglais et français.

ou par:

> Le lundi, j'ai les maths, l'histoire, l'anglais et le français.

Dans le livre de texte de l'élève il y a l'exemple: « on a maths ».

Peut-on en conclure de supprimer l'article défini, comme dans la première phrase, ou est-ce que c'est mieux d'employer l'article défini, comme dans la deuxième phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Généralement, dire "j'ai les/des maths" sous-entend "j'ai les/des maths **à faire**", donc qu'il aurait des devoirs dans cette matière (idem pour les autres matières, du coup).

Quand on veut parler de son emploi du temps, on cite la matière sans mettre d'article. La première proposition est donc la plus adaptée et juste. La 2e phrase est correcte mais elle n'est pas adaptée pour ce contexte.

Answer (score 4):

Effectivement, pour décrire les cours auxquels l'élève va assister, comme le contexte de la question initiale l'indique, on aura :

> *Lundi, j'ai* [cours de] *maths,* [cours d']*histoire,* [cours d']*anglais,* [cours de] *français, ...*

Si l'élève listait les devoirs qu'il a à faire chez lui en revanche, il utiliserait vraisemblablement les articles partitifs pour différencier :

> Pour demain, j'ai **des** maths, **de l'**histoire, **de l'**anglais, etc.

Enfin, s'il répondait à quelqu'un qui lui demande une liste de matières (quelles sont ses matières préférées par exemple), il utiliserait la variante avec l'article défini seul :

> J'aime les maths, l'histoire, l'anglais, ...

Comment: Il est aussi possible se passer du **de** dans les devoirs car on sous-entend **à faire**, bien que ce soit plus familier.

Comment: @iKiWiXz J'avoue avoir rarement entendu cette forme pour cet usage, mais je l'imagine assez facilement, ne serait-ce que par raccourci. Ca doit aussi fluctuer un peu selon les lieux.

Answer (score 1):

La première réponse est la bonne:

> Le lundi, j'ai maths, histoire, anglais et français.

La deuxième réponse est en revanche incorrecte car dans ce contexte, l'article défini "**le**" change le sens de la phrase.

- > "**Les maths**" font référence ici non pas à la matière scolaire mais à l'ensemble des connaissances mathématiques.
- > "**L'anglais**" fait référence ici à un homme de nationalité anglaise ou bien à la langue anglaise
- > "**Le français**" de la même façon, cela fait référence à un homme de nationalité française ou bien à langue anglaise.
- > "**L'histoire**" fait référence également à une histoire en particulier et nn à la matière.

Afin de corriger la deuxième phrase, il faut utiliser des ***articles partitif*** ou bien des ***articles défini contracté***

> Le lundi, j'ai **des** maths, **de** l'histoire, **de** l'anglais et **du** français.

Afin de vous entrainer, je vous conseille de [faire quelques exercices sur ce site](http://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/partitif_ou_contracte.htm).

Bonne chance.

Comment: Petite remarque, on met une majuscule à Français et Anglais lorsqu'on parle d'une personne de cette nationalité.

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE règle tout-à-fait authentique, tu as raison, mais j'avoue que j'ai toujours été perplexe devant cette étrangeté... le principe logique de n'attribuer une majuscule qu'aux noms propres (de lieux ou de personnes) aurait été tellement meilleur. Mais bien entendu les langues ne suivent pas prioritairement la logique, la part arbitraire et historique est toujours importante.

Comment: Au temps pour moi :-)

Comment: Pour la deuxième phrase il est possible de se passer des articles lors de l'énumération des matières scolaires.